# Android App opens and closes

Tags: android, build, android-logcat

Ive been trying to make a php POST app for a while now but all the examples I use don't work. This one below is the closest i have to work but the app opens and closes strait away. LOGCAT says

```
01-30 15:33:38.032 20535-20750/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=tv.gamepop.remote.logger/.RegistrationService } U=0: not found

01-30 15:33:38.502 20535-20778/system_process D/InputMethodManagerService: ime_enabled = false is same as last value, no change

01-30 15:33:38.502 20535-20778/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 5223 uid 10026
```

my code below

```
package au.com.industryresponsetraining.post;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText value;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
        value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

            // out of range
            Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());
        }


    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://industeryresponsetraning.com.au/mdt/add.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="au.com.industryresponsetraining.post">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

any help would be great to help me get this up and running

full logcat from opened till close

```
 -30 16:51:20.831 12994-13018/system_process W/ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
01-30 16:51:20.831 12994-13018/system_process W/ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
01-30 16:51:20.831 12994-13018/system_process I/PackageManager: Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl203661240
01-30 16:51:20.861 12994-13018/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 574K, 25% free 5967K/7920K, paused 20ms+0ms, total 30ms
01-30 16:51:20.881 12994-13018/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 387K, 22% free 6189K/7920K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-30 16:51:20.921 12994-13018/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1122K, 20% free 6402K/7920K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-30 16:51:20.941 12994-13018/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 980K, 20% free 6409K/7920K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-30 16:51:20.971 12994-13018/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 982K, 19% free 6417K/7920K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-30 16:51:21.011 12994-13009/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping au.com.industryresponsetraining.post appid=10068 user=-1: uninstall pkg
01-30 16:51:21.011 12994-13009/system_process I/ActivityManager: Setting mBooting value to false, currently mBooted = true
01-30 16:51:21.031 12994-13018/system_process I/PackageManager: Package au.com.industryresponsetraining.post codePath changed from /data/app/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post-1.apk to /data/app/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
01-30 16:51:21.051 12994-13018/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 19% free 6436K/7920K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 20ms
01-30 16:51:21.051 12994-13018/system_process I/PackageManager: Running dexopt on: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
01-30 16:51:21.361 12994-13018/system_process W/PackageManager: Code path for pkg : au.com.industryresponsetraining.post changing from /data/app/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post-1.apk to /data/app/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post-2.apk
01-30 16:51:21.361 12994-13018/system_process W/PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : au.com.industryresponsetraining.post changing from /data/app/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post-1.apk to /data/app/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post-2.apk
01-30 16:51:21.371 12994-13009/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping au.com.industryresponsetraining.post appid=10068 user=-1: update pkg
01-30 16:51:21.371 12994-13009/system_process I/ActivityManager: Setting mBooting value to false, currently mBooted = true
01-30 16:51:21.411 12994-13018/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping au.com.industryresponsetraining.post appid=10068 user=0: pkg removed
01-30 16:51:21.431 12994-13009/system_process I/ActivityManager: Setting mBooting value to false, currently mBooted = true
01-30 16:51:21.441 12994-13032/system_process I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
01-30 16:51:21.451 12994-12994/system_process D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:au.com.industryresponsetraining.post flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
01-30 16:51:21.461 12994-13009/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.musicfx for broadcast com.android.musicfx/.Compatibility$Receiver: pid=18301 uid=10001 gids={50001, 3003, 3002}
01-30 16:51:21.471 12994-13010/system_process W/LocationProviderProxy-fused: com.google.android.gms resolves service com.android.location.service.FusedLocationProvider, but has wrong signature, ignoring
01-30 16:51:21.471 12994-13010/system_process W/RecognitionManagerService: no available voice recognition services found for user 0
01-30 16:51:21.481 12994-13032/system_process I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
01-30 16:51:21.511 12994-12994/system_process D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:au.com.industryresponsetraining.post flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
01-30 16:51:21.591 12994-13006/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delay finish: com.bluestacks.home/.KeyMappingDownloader$PackageModifiedRecevier
01-30 16:51:21.591 12994-13065/system_process I/ActivityManager: Resuming delayed broadcast
01-30 16:51:21.611 12994-13065/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.keychain for broadcast com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver: pid=18328 uid=1000 gids={41000, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3002, 3001, 3003}
01-30 16:51:21.641 12994-13138/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 15779:com.google.android.gms.wearable/u0a19 (adj 15): empty #6
01-30 16:51:21.681 12994-13018/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 1836K, 24% free 6073K/7952K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 220ms
01-30 16:51:21.731 12994-13005/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.google.android.partnersetup for broadcast com.google.android.partnersetup/.RlzPingBroadcastReceiver: pid=18345 uid=10018 gids={50018, 3003}
01-30 16:51:21.751 12994-13287/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delaying start of: ServiceRecord{329f6078 u0 com.google.android.gms/.wearable.service.WearableControlService}
01-30 16:51:21.771 12994-13196/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.google.android.gms.wearable for service com.google.android.gms/.wearable.service.WearableControlService: pid=18363 uid=10019 gids={50019, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3002, 3001, 3007, 2001, 3006}
01-30 16:51:21.771 12994-13006/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 16205:android.process.media/u0a12 (adj 15): empty #6
01-30 16:51:21.771 12994-13006/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
01-30 16:51:21.861 12994-13221/system_process I/ActivityManager: Resuming delayed broadcast
01-30 16:51:21.861 12994-13006/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delay finish: com.bluestacks.home/.KeyMappingDownloader$PackageModifiedRecevier
01-30 16:51:21.871 12994-13139/system_process I/ActivityManager: Resuming delayed broadcast
01-30 16:51:21.891 12994-13139/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=18386 uid=10047 gids={50047, 1028, 1015, 1023}
01-30 16:51:21.891 12994-13194/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 18328:com.android.keychain/1000 (adj 15): empty #6
01-30 16:51:21.901 12994-13006/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 18301:com.android.musicfx/u0a1 (adj 15): empty #6
01-30 16:51:22.031 12994-13218/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.musicfx for broadcast com.android.musicfx/.Compatibility$Receiver: pid=18408 uid=10001 gids={50001, 3003, 3002}
01-30 16:51:22.031 12994-13005/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delay finish: com.android.musicfx/.Compatibility$Receiver
01-30 16:51:22.041 12994-13065/system_process I/ActivityManager: Resuming delayed broadcast
01-30 16:51:22.051 12994-13138/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
01-30 16:51:22.061 12994-13218/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 16173:com.android.vending/u0a16 (adj 15): empty #6
01-30 16:51:22.101 12994-13287/system_process I/ActivityManager: Resuming delayed broadcast
01-30 16:51:22.121 12994-13287/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1055K, 25% free 6018K/7952K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-30 16:51:22.161 12994-13065/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.auth.be.account.AccountStatusChecker$InitializeReceiver
01-30 16:51:22.181 12994-13005/system_process I/ActivityManager: Resuming delayed broadcast
01-30 16:51:22.361 12994-13218/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main} from pid 18407
01-30 16:51:22.361 12994-13218/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post activityName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post.Main callingPackage: null  bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-30 16:51:22.371 12994-13218/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
01-30 16:51:22.391 12994-13218/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 567K, 25% free 5984K/7952K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-30 16:51:22.391 12994-13218/system_process I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.993MB for 124212-byte allocation
01-30 16:51:22.421 12994-13008/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 25% free 6096K/8076K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
01-30 16:51:22.421 12994-13221/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post activityName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-30 16:51:22.431 12994-13221/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
01-30 16:51:22.451 12994-13221/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc au.com.industryresponsetraining.post for activity au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main: pid=18445 uid=10068 gids={50068, 3003}
01-30 16:51:22.461 12994-13196/system_process D/WindowManager: in computeScreenConfigurationLocked() -- hardKeyboardAvailable :true  mHardKeyboardAvailable :true   mHardKeyboardEnabled :true
01-30 16:51:22.541 12994-13013/system_process D/WindowManager: Sending appClickStats request with data: [package=au.com.industryresponsetraining.post, appname=Post, appver=1.0, clickloc=system_server]
01-30 16:51:22.551 12994-13218/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process au.com.industryresponsetraining.post (pid 18445) has died.
01-30 16:51:22.551 12994-13218/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post activityName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-30 16:51:22.551 12994-13218/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
01-30 16:51:22.571 12994-13218/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc au.com.industryresponsetraining.post for activity au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main: pid=18465 uid=10068 gids={50068, 3003}
01-30 16:51:22.581 12994-13005/system_process D/WindowManager: in computeScreenConfigurationLocked() -- hardKeyboardAvailable :true  mHardKeyboardAvailable :true   mHardKeyboardEnabled :true
01-30 16:51:22.621 12994-13006/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process au.com.industryresponsetraining.post (pid 18465) has died.
01-30 16:51:22.621 12994-13006/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post activityName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-30 16:51:22.621 12994-13006/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
01-30 16:51:22.641 12994-13006/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc au.com.industryresponsetraining.post for activity au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main: pid=18482 uid=10068 gids={50068, 3003}
01-30 16:51:22.651 12994-13138/system_process D/WindowManager: in computeScreenConfigurationLocked() -- hardKeyboardAvailable :true  mHardKeyboardAvailable :true   mHardKeyboardEnabled :true
01-30 16:51:22.691 12994-13139/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process au.com.industryresponsetraining.post (pid 18482) has died.
01-30 16:51:22.691 12994-13139/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{3293342c u0 au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main t4}: app died, no saved state
01-30 16:51:22.691 12994-13139/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome activityName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-30 16:51:22.701 12994-13139/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome
01-30 16:51:22.701 12994-13139/system_process D/WindowManager: in computeScreenConfigurationLocked() -- hardKeyboardAvailable :true  mHardKeyboardAvailable :true   mHardKeyboardEnabled :true
01-30 16:51:23.241 12994-13194/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@3272635c attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@3298c86c
01-30 16:51:23.241 12994-13218/system_process I/ActivityManager: Setting mBooting value to false, currently mBooted = true
01-30 16:51:23.531 12994-13008/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{328c98a4 ActivityRecord{3286cc18 u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 16:51:23.531 12994-13008/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{328c98a4 ActivityRecord{3286cc18 u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 16:51:30.911 12994-13005/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 18345:com.google.android.partnersetup/u0a18 (adj 15): empty #6
01-30 16:51:32.091 12994-13032/system_process I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
01-30 16:51:32.111 12994-13221/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1351K, 25% free 6058K/8076K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-30 16:51:32.121 12994-13221/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.vending for broadcast com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.receivers.PackageMonitorReceiver$RegisteredReceiver: pid=18591 uid=10016 gids={50016, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023}
01-30 16:51:32.181 12994-13010/system_process W/LocationProviderProxy-fused: com.google.android.gms resolves service com.android.location.service.FusedLocationProvider, but has wrong signature, ignoring
01-30 16:51:32.211 12994-13138/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc android.process.media for content provider com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadProvider: pid=18623 uid=10012 gids={50012, 1028, 1015, 1023, 1024, 2001, 3003, 3007}
01-30 16:51:32.221 12994-13139/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 18408:com.android.musicfx/u0a1 (adj 15): empty #6
01-30 16:51:32.221 12994-13139/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 18386:com.svox.pico/u0a47 (adj 15): empty #7
01-30 16:51:34.281 12994-13032/system_process E/InputDispatcher: Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
01-30 16:51:34.431 12994-13032/system_process E/InputDispatcher: Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
01-30 16:51:34.481 12994-13287/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.bluestacks.gamepophome (pid 13219) has died.
01-30 16:51:34.481 12994-13138/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{3298c9a8 u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_}
01-30 16:51:34.481 12994-13287/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome activityName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-30 16:51:34.491 12994-13287/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome
01-30 16:51:34.511 12994-13287/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.bluestacks.gamepophome for activity com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_: pid=18679 uid=10026 gids={50026, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3002}
01-30 16:51:34.551 12994-13194/system_process D/WindowManager: in computeScreenConfigurationLocked() -- hardKeyboardAvailable :true  mHardKeyboardAvailable :true   mHardKeyboardEnabled :true
01-30 16:51:34.691 12994-13006/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=tv.gamepop.remote.logger/.RegistrationService } U=0: not found
01-30 16:51:35.101 12994-13221/system_process D/InputMethodManagerService: ime_enabled = false is same as last value, no change
01-30 16:51:35.101 12994-13221/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 13219 uid 10026
01-30 16:51:35.111 12994-13008/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_: +620ms
01-30 16:51:35.111 12994-13008/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{328c98a4 ActivityRecord{3286cc18 u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 16:51:35.111 12994-13008/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{328c98a4 ActivityRecord{3286cc18 u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 16:51:35.311 12994-13008/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{328c98a4 ActivityRecord{3286cc18 u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 16:51:35.471 12994-13005/system_process I/ActivityManager: Setting mBooting value to false, currently mBooted = true
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelstiveLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Enter Something Below:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="showZiare"/>
</RelstiveLayout>
```

**EDIT**: have updated logcat after removing Progress bar thinking that was the issue

Logcat from run

```
01-30 18:47:00.159 28194-28275/system_process E/InputDispatcher: Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
01-30 18:47:00.249 28194-28275/system_process E/InputDispatcher: Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
01-30 18:47:00.309 28194-28452/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.bluestacks.gamepophome (pid 28457) has died.
01-30 18:47:00.309 28194-28301/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{32996a98 u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_}
01-30 18:47:00.309 28194-28452/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome activityName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-30 18:47:00.309 28194-28452/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome
01-30 18:47:00.339 28194-28452/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.bluestacks.gamepophome for activity com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_: pid=30555 uid=10026 gids={50026, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3002}
01-30 18:47:00.359 28194-28301/system_process D/WindowManager: in computeScreenConfigurationLocked() -- hardKeyboardAvailable :true  mHardKeyboardAvailable :true   mHardKeyboardEnabled :true
01-30 18:47:00.489 28194-28301/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=tv.gamepop.remote.logger/.RegistrationService } U=0: not found
01-30 18:47:00.579 28194-28301/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1196K, 21% free 6200K/7832K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-30 18:47:00.969 28194-28207/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{32928b38 ActivityRecord{32928a0c u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 18:47:00.989 28194-28207/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_: +660ms
01-30 18:47:00.999 28194-28207/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{32928b38 ActivityRecord{32928a0c u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 18:47:01.009 28194-28452/system_process D/InputMethodManagerService: ime_enabled = false is same as last value, no change
01-30 18:47:01.009 28194-28452/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 28457 uid 10026
01-30 18:47:01.199 28194-28207/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{32928b38 ActivityRecord{32928a0c u0 com.bluestacks.gamepophome/tv.gamepop.home.GamePopMain_ t1}}
01-30 18:47:02.799 28194-28416/system_process I/ActivityManager: Setting mBooting value to false, currently mBooted = true
```

debug console (if it helps)

```
Target device: emulator-5554
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Users\Shane\AndroidStudioProjects\Post\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Force stopping package: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
Launching application: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post.Main.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/au.com.industryresponsetraining.post.Main" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=au.com.industryresponsetraining.post/.Main }

Waiting for process: au.com.industryresponsetraining.post
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:9514', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:9514', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: need more information shaggs..what u mean by app opening and closing,app is getting crash?

Comment: @shaggs post your layout also and full logcat since after launching the app to automatically crashing.

Comment: @AsifSb the app opens and closes but nothing is shown. im using bluestack. tried on my mobile same thing only message is "unfortunately app has stopped"

Comment: u added the details lemme check

Comment: @shagss please try to catch precise logs this one doesn't tell much  ... As a side note do UN-install from device and then do clean at IDE and then install again.... BTW which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Android studio will do other part shortly

Comment: On logcat what output would you like e.g system and shall i run as debug app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was because of you misspelled RelativeLayout to "RelstiveLayout" and there is no class available in Android with such name that is way application was straight away crashing right after launching.

Change

```
<RelstiveLayout
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
```

That's it.

Also as a Side note Do this also because it's useless for your case you are implementing OnClickListner within Activity itself.
From layout file 's button section

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="showZiare"/>
```

Remove

`android:onClick="****"` attribute from your layout xml for button.

and you are good to go :)

Comment: If i remove the onclick feom activity section my btn.setonclicklistener goes red. So if i remove from the top how do i handle my onclick?

Comment: I changed to LinearLayout before post was placed but am more than happy to accept this as its the true reason

Comment: @shaggs Pleasure is all mine Thanks :)